# Error in facebook.graphApi and facebook-sdk uninstall

Tags: python, facebook

At the beginning I did this

```py
!pip3 install facebook-sdk

graph = facebook.graphApI(access_token=user_long_token, version=8.3)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\PARAME~1\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_8392/971760545.py in <module>
----> 1 graph = facebook.graphApI(access_token=user_long_token, version=8.3)

AttributeError: module 'facebook' has no attribute 'graphApI'
```

How to uninstall the facebook-sdk and resolve this attribute error?

Answer (score 0):

To uninstall simply do `pip uninstall <packagename>` with regards to the error are you sure you are calling it the correct way? I mean methods are case sensitive ... I think the method is called `facebook.GraphAPI()` See [reference](https://facebook-sdk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#class-facebook-graphapi)

Comment: I couldn't solve this in jupiter notebook but it works in google colab.